# What is the name of this red plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I came across this plant yesterday (14th May) and was wondering what it might be? Would anybody know the scientific name and if it's indigenous to the UK (personally I doubt it is)? The plant grows in an Asian style garden near [Cumnock, Scotland](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/The+Great+Steward+of+Scotland's+Dumfries+House+Trust/@55.455564,-4.310152,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4888285c7c0209a5:0xbb95a95acaee65a!8m2!3d55.455561!4d-4.307958).

[image]

Close up of leaves:

[image]

Comment: I keep seeing this in the Hot Network Questions, misreading it as "What is the name of this red planet?" and thinking, "It's Mars, duh."

Comment: I'm pretty sure the sun is the only red planet /s

Comment: Yes this is Acer Palmatum . We have one in a container in our garden which is twenty years old and does look amazing when in full leaf. It is completely hardy though hard late spring frosts might affect leaves already out.

Comment: Red? Something wrong with your photo or your colour vision.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is the "[Acer palmatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_palmatum)" or Japanese maple, which shows a wide variety of different leaf forms (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_palmatum)):

[image]

Specically you found "Acer palmatum dissectum 'Red Dragon'", for more information look [here](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=257201) (picture also from this site):

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the quick answer. I am well impressed.

Answer (score 11):

Looks like a cultivar of the [Japanse maple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_palmatum) (*Acer palmatum*). I assume that is why you have found it in an Asian stlye garden. There are various cultivars that differ by color and shape of the leaves, as you can see in this picture form Wikipedia:[image]

**Image source:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_palmatum#/media/File:Acer-palmatum-ssp.jpg

Answer (score -1):

It's an acer dissectum ( spelling may not be quite right!). It is Japanese and one of a number of similar plants from there. Becoming popular in UK.  Needs slightly acid soil, PH of about 6. semi shade and shelter from winds

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Why do you answer a question that has already been answered and provide the same answer (without references, and actually borderline wrong as this is not *A. dissectum* - which does not exist - but *A. palmatum* in the dissectum variant) as the accepted answer? Your answer as is might be down-voted or deleted. Please take a look at the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) and [the guidelines for good answers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!